# Ember Data won't fetch from API

Tags: ember.js, ember-data

Even though i have set the RESPAdapter to take care of everything, it doesn't reach out to my server to get the data. My code is:

```
var App = Ember.Application.create({
  LOG_TRANSITIONS: true
});

App.ApplicationAdapter = DS.RESTAdapter.extend({
  host: '../api/'
});

App.Me = DS.Model.extend({
    email: DS.attr('string'),
    firstname: DS.attr('string'),
    lastname: DS.attr('string')
});

App.WelcomemessageController = Ember.Controller.extend({
    firstname:"I get rendered as i should",
    model: function() {
        return this.store.find('me');
    }
});
```

And yeah, the property "firstname" gets rendered out just fine. And when inspecting with Chrome Devtools, no requests are being made.

Comment: Are you sure this is your code?  That isn't valid javascript in your controller.  That aside, the model hook belongs on the route, not the controller.

Comment: oh sorry, yeah, of course there should be a , after the firstname property, that got lost. But can't i set a model on the controller? The Welcommessage-view gets rendered outside the outlet, which means the Welcomemessage is visible on every route. So where should i put it then?

Comment: Please check the [guides](http://emberjs.com/guides/routing/setting-up-a-controller/). The `model: fn` belongs to the Route. The controller does have a **property** named `model` but that's supposed to be a data container rather than a fetching function. The route is responsible for fetching the data and make that data available for the controller.

Comment: So by having this Controller outside the route, as it is visible on all pages, and exists outside the {{outlet}}, it has no route to exist in. So how can i populate the controller with data then?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your case you just want to use a computed property, and not the model function.  you could call it model, but it'd be slightly confusing since generally a controller decorates a model, and in this case it'd just be a property called model on the controller (in order to decorate a model, the controller needs to be an `ObjectController` or `ArrayController`)

```
App.WelcomemessageController = Ember.Controller.extend({
    firstname:"I get rendered as i should",
    user: function() {
        return this.store.find('me');
    }.property()
});
```

Comment: It still doesn't make any requests to the server, and the model in the Ember chrome-plugin is still empty.

Comment: computed properties are lazily computed.  If you aren't calling `user` in your template Ember isn't going to waste the time computing the property.

Comment: Thanks, that was a very important fact!